# ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: Exception in doCheckpoint

Tags: hadoop

I'm using Hadoop 2.2.0 in a Cluster setup and I repeatedly get the following error, the Exception is produced in the name node olympus under file `/opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/hadoop-deploy-secondarynamenode-olympus.log` e.g.

```
2014-02-12 16:19:59,013 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@olympus:50090
2014-02-12 16:19:59,013 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: Web server init done
2014-02-12 16:19:59,013 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: Secondary Web-server up at: olympus:50090
2014-02-12 16:19:59,013 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: Checkpoint Period   :3600 secs (60 min)
2014-02-12 16:19:59,013 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: Log Size Trigger    :1000000 txns
2014-02-12 16:20:59,161 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: Exception in doCheckpoint
java.io.IOException: Inconsistent checkpoint fields.
LV = -47 namespaceID = 291272852 cTime = 0 ; clusterId = CID-e3e4ac32-7384-4a1f-9dce-882a6e2f4bd4 ; blockpoolId = BP-166254569-192.168.92.21-1392217748925.
Expecting respectively: -47; 431978717; 0; CID-85b65e19-4030-445b-af8e-5933e75a6e5a; BP-1963497814-192.168.92.21-1392217083597.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.CheckpointSignature.validateStorageInfo(CheckpointSignature.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.doCheckpoint(SecondaryNameNode.java:519)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.doWork(SecondaryNameNode.java:380)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode$2.run(SecondaryNameNode.java:346)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.doAsLoginUserOrFatal(SecurityUtil.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.run(SecondaryNameNode.java:342)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
2014-02-12 16:21:59,183 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: Exception in doCheckpoint
java.io.IOException: Inconsistent checkpoint fields.
LV = -47 namespaceID = 291272852 cTime = 0 ; clusterId = CID-e3e4ac32-7384-4a1f-9dce-882a6e2f4bd4 ; blockpoolId = BP-166254569-192.168.92.21-1392217748925.
Expecting respectively: -47; 431978717; 0; CID-85b65e19-4030-445b-af8e-5933e75a6e5a; BP-1963497814-192.168.92.21-1392217083597.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.CheckpointSignature.validateStorageInfo(CheckpointSignature.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.doCheckpoint(SecondaryNameNode.java:519)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.doWork(SecondaryNameNode.java:380)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode$2.run(SecondaryNameNode.java:346)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.doAsLoginUserOrFatal(SecurityUtil.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.run(SecondaryNameNode.java:342)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Can anyone advice what's wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same error and it went when I deleted the [hadoop temporary directory] `/dfs/namesecondary` directory.

For me [hadoop temporary directory] is the value of `hadoop.tmp.dir` in `core-site.xml`

Comment: can you please tell here, how is it possible to delete [hadoop temporary directory]/dfs/namesecondary? Where I can find it and how is it possible to remove it? thank you in advance

Comment: Stop hadoop, then you need to look in core-site.xml. Find the value of hadoop.tmp.dir (for me /home/vm/tmp), then simply browse to  e.g. /home/vm/tmp/dfs and delete the namesecondary folder (assuming you are using linux).

Comment: Does anyone know why this is happening? It's happened to me a few times, after everything seems OK and then the next job won't launch. This just doesn't seem as stable as I know Hadoop must be.  What's causing this??

Answer (score 2):

We need to stop the hadoop services first , and then delete the tmp secondary namenode directory (`hadoop.tmp.dir` will tell the path for secondary namenode data directory). After this, start the services again and the issue will be fixed.