# Hadoop doesn't recognize the slave

Tags: hadoop, master-slave

I have the Hadoop installation on my local machine and on my slave node. I want to use it for the multinode cluster (master + 1 slave currently). I also read the [hadoop multinode tutorial](http://bigdatahandler.com/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-multi-node-cluster-setup/) and try to run my hadoop on master and slave.
I have the next configuration of my system. After I upgrade the `hdfs-site.xml` and `core-site.xml`, I define the masters and slaves on the local machine. In `masters` I put `localhost`, in `slaves` I put the name of the slave node... On the slave I only definied the `slaves` with `localhost`
After that I execute

```
hduser@user:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2$ sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

in the local repository. The hadoop answer in the terminal seems to be good:

```
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-user.out
hduser@slavename: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-slavename.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-user.out
```

Finally I go in `localhost:50070` and I didn't see any slave node under `LiveNodes`

[image]

I suppose, I don't have connection to my slave, anyway I didn't get any error message during the cluster start. After I do a stop of dfs, I really got the message:

```
Stopping namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: stopping namenode
hduser@slavename: no datanode to stop
Stopping secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: stopping secondarynamenode
```

Consequently my slave node is not connected to the master....

I also see in my log file in logs. The error message is :

```
java.io.IOException: Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
```

How I can connect my master to my slave?

**PS** I can actually use hadoop as a master without any slaves, I can also run the spark code with the input from local hadoop installation in the local mode... The main problem is just a slave.

Answer (score 0):

Your masters file name should contain the address of the SecondaryNameNode so that NameNode can read it.You need to configure your **fs.default.name** on **core-site.xml** configuration file like :

```
<property>
   <name>fs.default.name</name>
   <value>hdfs://master:9000</value>
</property>
```

Also you should check on how **" hdfs namenode -format "** works in Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to setup passwordless SSH login between Master and slave node.

Then define all the required configuration. Check the core-site.xml file

```
<property>
 <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
 <value>hdfs://namenode:8020</value>
</property>
```

Follow following steps:

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR = $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
echo $HADOOP_CONF_DIR
hdfs namenode -format
hdfs getconf -namenodes
./start-dfs.sh
```

It should solve your problem.

Comment: thank you, it doesn't help. I message below for you the complete error messages from the both log files (for DataNode and for SecondaryNameNode). Can you please take a look? Thank you

Comment: Refer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732988/error-org-apache-hadoop-hdfs-server-namenode-secondarynamenode-exception-in-doc). It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your ssh connectivity is established or not between 2 nodes.
2. Check whether u have defined the correct ip address on the slaves file in NN.

Answer (score 0):

@Nishu Tayal, thank you for your information. Actually I already updated all the files like in hadoop tutorial (and consequently how you tell me here). Also `core-site.xml` is ok. I also run the order `bin/hdfs namenode -format` from the hadoop folder and didn't get any error messages. After I executed `sbin/start-dfs.sh` I got the error in the log file `hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-user.log`:

```
java.io.IOException: Inconsistent checkpoint fields.
LV = -63 namespaceID = 1073223169 cTime = 0 ; clusterId = CID-66f842d0-e32e-4590-b8be-c4f4ff898c4d ; blockpoolId = BP-160655376-127.0.1.1-1461593248732.
Expecting respectively: -63; 1554470454; 0; CID-6388cf98-8302-48ab-8cd4-44e99ff3d9cb; BP-536690032-127.0.1.1-1461566958202.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.CheckpointSignature.validateStorageInfo(CheckpointSignature.java:134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.doCheckpoint(SecondaryNameNode.java:531)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.doWork(SecondaryNameNode.java:395)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode$1.run(SecondaryNameNode.java:361)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.doAsLoginUserOrFatal(SecurityUtil.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.run(SecondaryNameNode.java:357)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-04-25 16:10:23,821 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: Exception in doCheckpoint
```

And in the log file `hadoop-hduser-datanode-user.log`

```
2016-04-26 09:10:37,087 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Exiting. 
java.io.IOException: All specified directories are failed to load.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:478)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initStorage(DataNode.java:1358)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initBlockPool(DataNode.java:1323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.verifyAndSetNamespaceInfo(BPOfferService.java:317)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.connectToNNAndHandshake(BPServiceActor.java:223)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:802)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Probably the error mesage from secondarynamenode is not relevant, is from yesterday. Today at morning I didn't get any error messages in this file.